# Ext JS Classic 7.1 + Modern theme: binding fieldLabel and emptyText doesn't work

Tags: extjs

When trying to bind fieldLabel and emptyText for localization purposes, the Classic Material theme doesn't work properly, but puts the texts on top of each other, see https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/34qe

Are there any known work-arounds to this? 
Using Ext JS 7.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can provide **default field Label**. The issue you face could be because viewModel is bound to view AFTER render event